# onUserInteraction method not working when reEntering in the activity?

Tags: android

I have an activity I used a timer here and and want it to reset on user interaction changed, it is working fine, but after I reenter the Activity, `onUserinteraction` method is not called when user touches the screen.

```
   @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
            super.onUserInteraction();
            // reset the timer with user interaction
            if (flag == 0) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer.start();
          }
    }
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction())

> Called whenever a key, touch, or trackball event is dispatched to the
>   activity. Implement this method if you wish to know that the user has
>   interacted with the device in some way while your activity is running.
>   This callback and onUserLeaveHint() are intended to help activities
>   manage status bar notifications intelligently; specifically, for
>   helping activities determine the proper time to cancel a notfication.
>
> All calls to your activity's onUserLeaveHint() callback will be
>   accompanied by calls to onUserInteraction(). This ensures that your
>   activity will be told of relevant user activity such as pulling down
>   the notification pane and touching an item there.
>
> Note that this callback will be invoked for the touch down action that
>   begins a touch gesture, but may not be invoked for the touch-moved and
>   touch-up actions that follow.

It's called only when the user interacts with the device

Comment: How does this answer the original question?